# What's the exact button I need to press to speed up conversations and crafting?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

So far I've done nothing but mash all the buttons on my Joycons when trying to speed up conversations and crafting, but can't seem to figure out which exact button speeds up the actions, as when I try individual buttons one by one during the process, they don't seem to speed it up at all. Is this because I have to mash buttons in order to speed up conversations and crafting?  Or is there an exact button I'm supposed to press to speed these up?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to press <kbd>A</kbd> twice to speed up crafting.

You need to press <kbd>B</kbd> once to speed up conversations.

Comment: You can also press L or R to speed up conversations.